# JAWS read label on selected select element

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

If I tab to a select JAWS will read the label and value. If I make a selection then navigate away then back JAWS will only read the selected value.

Is there any way to have the screen reader read the label as well as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is semantically correct, then don't worry about minor differences in how screen readers announce form elements.  JAWS, NVDA, and VoiceOver all have their nuances.  Can you describe or post what your code looks like?  If it's something like this, then you're ok:

```html
<label for='myselect'>here is my label</label>
<select id='myselect'>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

The `<label>` element points to the `<select>` by using the `for` attribute.  As long as the label and select are tied together this way, then how the screen reader treats it is somewhat out of your control.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. The issue was with Chrome on OSX, the behaviour wasn't consistent with Safari and Firefox.